# JsonIgnore on field in list of objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have applied JsonIgnore annotation on a field in class.

```
public class User {

private String name;

@JsonIgnore
private String id;

public String getName(){ return this.name;}
public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }

public String getId() { return this.id; }
public void setId(String id) {this.id = id; }

}
```

When the class object is returned as single object, the field gets ignored.

```
public ResponseEntity<User> get() {.... some code to get user and return User object}
```

However, when the list of object is returned as response, the field is not getting ignored and still present in response.

```
ProjectController.java
@RequestMapping(value="/{projectId}/users", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> list(
            @ApiParam(value = "projectId")
            @PathVariable UUID projectId) {
        return ok(projectsService.getUsers(projectId));
    }
```

```
ProjectService.java
public List<User> getUsers(UUID projectId) {

// Some code here to fetch the data from another container , so framing URI here and sending the req
            String response = HttpUtils.getRequest(uri);
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, List.class);
    }
```

Could you please help on how to ignore the field completely from sending in responses.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Post the code from controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `response` variable in `ProjectService` class looks something like this:

```
 String response = "[\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "    \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"Test\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "]";
```

You are trying to convert your json to a `List.class`, not a list of users `List<User>`, so
change this line of code:

```
return new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, List.class);
```

to this:

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, new TypeReference<List<User>>(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add @JsonIgnore to the fields (getter in this case) instead of directly to the property

```
@JsonIgnore
public String getId() { return this.id; }
```

Comment: No, this did not work. Still the same result.

Comment: which dependencies are you using for jackson?

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson 2.10.1

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem and couldn't. It worked for me. So may be it is the version of your library. Here is the versions I used:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
          <version>2.13.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
          <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

And here is the code I ran:

```
private static void jsonParserIgnoreTest() {
    try {
        JsonPerson person = new JsonPerson(1L, "Jack");
        System.out.println("Single person: " + JsonUtils.writeObjectToJsonString(person));
        List<JsonPerson> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(person);
        JsonGroup group = new JsonGroup("Interest Group", list);


        System.out.println("Group: " + JsonUtils.writeObjectToJsonString(group));
        System.out.println("List: " + JsonUtils.writeObjectToJsonString(list));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is the output I got:

```
Single person: {"name":"Jack"}
Group: {"groupName":"Interest Group","people":[{"name":"Jack"}]}
List: [{"name":"Jack"}]
```

Here are the classes JsonPerson and JsonGroup (omitting setters and getters)

```
public class JsonPerson {
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public JsonPerson() {
    }
    public JsonPerson(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class JsonGroup {
    String groupName;
    List<JsonPerson> people;

    public JsonGroup() {
    }

    public JsonGroup(String name, List<JsonPerson> people) {
        groupName = name;
        this.people = people;
    }

}
```

The class `JsonUtils` - a thin wrapper over Jackson-Json Library. It is part of Open source MgntUtils library written and maintained by me. If you are interested you can use it too. Here is [JsonUtils Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html) and the library could be obtained as [Maven artifact On Maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including sources and Javadoc)